# "error code 1" Installing usaddress with Anaconda on Windows 7 32-bit

Tags: windows, python-2.7, installation, anaconda, python-3.5

I am running Windows 7 and Anaconda. Attempting to install usaddress library found here: https://github.com/datamade/usaddress I have attempted this installation using a `virtual env` of Python 2.7 in my Anaconda3 installation, and a separately installed Anaconda 2.

I installed `pip` for Conda and navigated to my `Scripts` directory to attempt an install using `pip install usaddress`. It does not work, neither do many of the solutions that I have found on the internet. The error I get is this:

***Command "C:\Users\User\Anaconda2\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='c:\users\user\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-0a_vd7\python-crfsuite\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open'
, open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record c:\users\user\appdata\local\temp\pip-mtrojm-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in c:\users\user\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-0a_vd7\python-crfsuite***

This is another error that seems to pop up:

```
 Failed building wheel for python-crfsuite
 Running setup.py clean for python-crfsuite
 Failed to build python-crfsuite
```

I have also attempted to fix this error with no luck by searching Stack and other places on the internet.

Comment: Do you have a c/c++ compiler on the system path? Like Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 - the python-crfsuite can't build. It needs a C compiler like GCC on Linux. https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48145